# How do I get facebook access token in c# codebhind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just managed to log in using facebook on my site. However all this is done in javascript. I need to access my access token from codebehind in order to check things like "Has this user already voted?" "Is this user verified using membership or facebook"?

I simply need to get the token in codebehind and access the ID and verified-status. I get this atm using `JSON.stringify`

```
{"id":"101536251398","email":"email@gmail.com","first_name":"Fname","gender":"male","last_name":"LName","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/101536251398/","locale":"sv_SE","name":"Fname Lname","timezone":9,"updated_time":"2015-01-15T11:36:46+0000","verified":true}!
```

I feel like it might not be the best solution to save this to a hiddenfield and then load the hiddenfield in codebehind.

Also, is it wrong to not add these user in my own database? It seems like a lot of extra work. All I really need to know is that they are verified. And if they do anything bad I can ban their facebook-id from my site?

Comment: you have to use .NET SDK client for facebook https://facebook.codeplex.com/

Comment: It says its outdated. they recommend facebook C# SDK

Comment: sorry try this one http://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook.Client or this  one http://facebooksdk.net/docs/reference/